# iOS Get http 400 when upload base64 encoded image to a RESTful server

Tags: ios, swift, spring, rest, base64

I am new to server side programming. Currently, I am developing a RESTful Server for an iOS app.

I am getting an HTTP response 400 and an error message 'The data couldn't read because it isn't in the correct format' when uploading an image from my iOS app to the RESTful server.

**Update**: Thank you for Codo's suggestion: "You should be more specific about where the error message occurs. My guess is it's when you parse the response in iOS. Your Swift code expects a JSON response. However, on the server side you just send a simple string. That doesn't fit. – Codo"

I add a Result class which only contains a String type message in server side. (It was a simply String response instead of class reponse.) And I added specific detail in the comment.

Additionally, I added some codes to check whether or not image data goes in 'createImage' method. It turns out the data never goes in 'createImage' class. The problem probably is caused by the incorrect way to transfer image data.

This is code in server side:

Result class:

```
public class Result {
  private String message;

  public String getMessage() {
      return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
  }

  public Result(String message) {
    super();
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value= "/images") 
public ResponseEntity<Result> createImage(@RequestParam("image") String file,@RequestParam("desc") String  desc){ 

  // check whether or not image data goes here
  try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:/cp/check.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("image data is processing");
        writer.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {

  }
  //** file is never created **//

  //** so nothing happens below **/
  if (!file.isEmpty()) {
    try {
      byte[] imageByte= parseBase64Binary(file);

      String directory="D:/cp/" + desc + ".jpg";

      new FileOutputStream(directory).write(imageByte);

      Result result = new Result("You have successfully uploaded ");

      return new ResponseEntity<Result>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Result result = new Result("You failed to upload ");
      return new ResponseEntity<Result>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
  } else {
    Result result = new Result("Unable to upload. File is empty.");
    return new ResponseEntity<Result>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

And this is code in iOS side:

```
let serviceUrl = URL(string:"http://192.168.0.17:8080/rest/images/")

var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"

let image = UIImage(named: "someImage")

let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

let base64: String! = data?.base64EncodedString()

let body = ["image": base64, "desc": "firstImage"]

do {    
  request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .prettyPrinted)

  let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { 

    (data, response, err) in

    guard err == nil else {
      // Always no error
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      return
    }

    let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse

    print(httpResponse)
    // <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17003bfa0> { URL:  http://192.168.0.17:8080/rest/images/ } 
    // { status code: 400, headers {
    // Connection = close;
    // "Content-Language" = en;
    // "Content-Length" = 1099;
    // "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
    // Date = "Tue, 27 Dec 2016 23:13:33 GMT";
    // } }

    do {
      let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
      // I pretty sure that parsing data as dictionary is correct because I used same code in many places and they work fine. 

      // code never reaches this line
      print(json.description)

    } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      // print: 'The data couldn't read because it isn't in the correct format'
      return
    }
  }

  session.resume()

} catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
  return
}
```

I already did a lot of research, but still cannot find a solution.

Comment: You should be more specific about where the error message occurs. My guess is it's when you parse the response in iOS. Your Swift code expects a JSON response. However, on the server side you just send a simple string. That doesn't fit.

Comment: Thank you for replying me so fast. I made some changes in the server side and add more specific details according to your suggestion

Comment: If you get HTTP error 400 (or any other HTTP error code) you must not try to parse the result as JSON. 400 is an error. So there's no valid response. It just creates the misleading error message. Instead, you should print the response so you can see the full error message returned by the web server. And you should probably set the content type of the URL request. Currently, it's unspecified.

Comment: I print the response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17003bfa0> { URL: http://192.168.0.17:8080/rest/images/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Language" = en;
    "Content-Length" = 1099;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 27 Dec 2016 23:13:33 GMT";
} }

Comment: It seems to be useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I find out a solution by myself. I hope it can help other beginners like me. Also, thanks for Codo's helps.

First, the reason I got 'The data couldn't read because it isn't in the correct format' is that I FORGOT to add **'Content-Type: application/json'** into header. The code in iOS side should be:

```
request.serValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Second, in server side, I change

`createImage(@RequestParam("image") String file,@RequestParam("desc") String  desc)`

to:

`createImage(@RequestBody Image  image)`

I use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`. The `image` class contains two files: `String file` and `String desc`.

That's all. It works for me.